# Creating Product variations automatically rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**EDIT: It works just fine**

Basically, a parent product is created, then if desired, multiple variations of that very product appear(different sizes) that are the products actually being sold. It saves a lot of content manager time specially if there are standard or expected variations.

I have this code to make auto-variations but it does not work for some reason.

```
VARIATIONS = ["Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large", "XX-Large", "XXX-Large"]

def create
  @product = Product.new product_params 
  if @product.save
    if @variations
      variations product_params
    end
    flash[:success] = "Product Added"
    redirect_to products_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def variations pparams
  VARIATIONS.each do |variation|
    product = Product.new title: "#{pparams[:title]} #{variation}", description: pparams[:description], price: pparams[:price], image: pparams[:image], isparent: false, parent_id: @product
    flash[:error] = "Error Creating Variations" unless product.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized the problem. The model had a uniqueness restriction on the description. If you do something like this in your future projects, save yourself a headache and check the model.